# Problem while defining conditions for multiple variables in C

Tags: c, loops, do-while

I'm trying to write a program in C that receives three integers and uses [This Method](https://www.wikihow.com/Determine-if-Three-Side-Lengths-Are-a-Triangle)

But I only want the inputs to be in the range of 1-100 (including 1 and 100)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a , b , c = 50;
    do{
        scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
    }
    while((a > 100 || a < 1)&& (b > 100 || b < 1) && (c > 100 || c < 1));
    
    if (a+b > c && a+c>b && b+c>a){
        printf("%d\n", a+b+c);
    }
    else {
        printf("invalid\n");
    }
```

And it somehow doesn't consider the conditions
for example if I enter something like `1000 -5 4` It won't reprompt me for a new input

But the weird thing is that if i only consider one of the conditions it will work fine with that one variable! for example if i put something like `while((a > 100 || a < 1);` in there, it will then reject an input like `1000 2 4`
How do I make it that it considers the conditions for all the variables?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Think about it: what will `(a > 100 || a < 1)&& (b > 100 || b < 1)` be for a=10 and b=1000?

Comment: You *must* check the value returned by scanf.  Always.  Without fail.  eg `while( scanf(...) == 3 && a > 100 ...)`

Comment: Because your program stucks here -> while((a > 100 || a < 1)&& (b > 100 || b < 1) && (c > 100 || c < 1)); Instead check the values with an if statment and use a boolean flag for the while loop.

Comment: Enable all warnings and debug info in your compiler. With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) use  `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and see [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check for any of the variable for range, change

```
 while((a > 100 || a < 1)&& (b > 100 || b < 1) && (c > 100 || c < 1));
                         ^^
 // Will produce a FALSE value if 'a' is within expected range, and due to
 // short-circuit, it'll not evaluate other conditions.
```

to

```
 while((a > 100 || a < 1) || (b > 100 || b < 1) || (c > 100 || c < 1));
```

That said, couple of other points:

- `int a , b , c = 50;` only initializes `c`, other variables are uninitialised and contain indeterminate values. Be a little more explicit, declare and define each variable in separate line (not a technical requirement, sake of readability and maintainability while being technically correct).
- Always check for the success of `scanf()`, before using the scanned values. Better, do away with `scanf()` for user inputs and use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: @RobertHarvey but if the first is already false, the && will short-circuit to false.

Answer (score 0):

more readable :

```
while(!( 1 <= a && a <= 100 && 1 <= b && b <= 100 && 1 <= c && c <= 100));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop will only continue if *all three* of `a`, `b`, and `c` are out of range - in your example of `1000 -5 4`, the condition `(c > 100 || c < 1)` evaluates to false (0), so the *whole expression* evaluates to false and the loop exits.

You need to change the sense of the test, such that it will continue if *any* of `a`, `b`, or `c` are out of range.  There are a couple of ways to do this:

```
while ( (a < 1 || a > 100) || (b < 1 || b > 100) || (c < 1 || c > 100) );
```

Changing the `&&` to `||` means that the expression will evaluate to true and the loop will continue if *any one* of `a`, `b`, or `c` are out of range.

Another option:

```
while ( !(1 <= a && a <= 100) && (1 <= b && b <= 100) && (1 <= c && c <= 100 ) );
```

This will cause the loop to exit if *all three* of `a`, `b`, and `c` are *in* range.

You should also check the result of `scanf` to make sure you read all 3 inputs:

```
do 
{
  if ( scanf ( "%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c ) != 3 ) )
  {
    if ( feof( stdin ) || ferror( stdin ) )
    {
      fputs( "Error or EOF on input, exiting", stderr );
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else
    {
      fputs( "Bad input detected, clearing input stream", stderr );
      /**
       * Read and discard everything up to the next newline character
       */
      while ( getchar() != '\n' )
        ; // empty loop
      
      /**
       * Unconditionally branch back to the beginning of the loop since 
       * at least one of a, b, and c wasn't read at all (i.e., don't
       * rely on the test since what you're testing isn't valid).  
       */
      continue;
    }
  }
} while ( (a < 1 || a > 100) || (b < 1 || b > 100) || (c < 1 || c > 100 ) );
```